# how to set a jformattedtextfield to take only 2 values?

Tags: java, jformattedtextfield

i know how to set a jformattedtextfield to allow the user to write only numbers, letters...but i want that a user can write only two values: 1 or 0.
How i can do that. I wrote this:

```
MaskFormatter mf6;
    try {
        mf6 = new MaskFormatter("#");
        txtformatted = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField(mf6);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want that a user can write only two values: 1 or 0.

Check out the `setValidCharacters(...)` method of the `MaskFormatter` class.